# How to pass result of filter operation in function?

Tags: angularjs, filter

In this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CBgcP/742/

I'm attempting to pass the result of a custom filter into a scoped function via an onclick :

```
 <span ng-click="open(friend.name | custom)")
```

This syntax is incorrect. Can the result of a filter operation be passed into a function via on-click ?

fiddle src :

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | weDontLike:'Adam'">
        <span ng-click="open(friend.name | custom)")>{{friend.name}}</span>
        <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
    </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>


span
{
 width: 200px;   
}


angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('weDontLike', function(){

    return function(items, name){

        var arrayToReturn = [];        
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            if (items[i].name != name) {
                arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
    };
});

angular.module('myApp', []).filter('custom', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.substring(0 , 2)
  };
});

function HelloCntl($scope) {

    $scope.open = function(){

        console.log('in open');
    }


     $scope.friends = [
        {
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1276'},
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'},
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321'},
    {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678'},
    {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765'}
    ];
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but try the inline syntax `<span ng-click="open(friend.name | filter:custom)">` *You also have an extra `)` in your element which needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `$filter` service to do this:

```
function HelloCntl($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.open = function(friend){

        console.log('in open with friend\'s name: ' + friend);
        console.log('friend\'s name with filter applied: ' + $filter('custom')(friend);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: + as you should not put any logic to view (html).